# No cameras available in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new to flutter.
Whenever
`final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);`
is called, the app crashes and throus this error:
`I/flutter (12496): Error picking image: PlatformException(no_available_camera, No cameras available for taking pictures., null, null)`

Sdk version is 21, i'm using my xiaomi mi 11 lite 5g with pixel experience and Android 13 to run the app, camera permission is already given when starting the app:

```
void startCamera() async {
  var cameras = await availableCameras();
  var cameraController = CameraController(
    cameras[0],
    ResolutionPreset.high,
    enableAudio: false,
  );
  await cameraController.initialize().then((value) {}).catchError((e) {
    print('error');
  });
}

onStart() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  startCamera();
  print('setup complete');
}
```

It runs fine on the chrome emulator. I've also noticed that after permissions are granted, the Android indicator for active camera comes out and stays there, like the camera was always active. On the other and, the pixel 6a emulator works fine, so I guess my phone's the problem. I also tried to buld the release apk but no luck there. Any ideas?

Update: sent to a fiend and it works fine on his end, so I guess my phone's the problem. I think he's running Android 14.

Complete code:

main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
//import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

void main() async {
  await onStart();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor:
        Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 134, 203), // navigation bar color
    statusBarColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231), // status bar color
  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

void startCamera() async {
  var cameras = await availableCameras();
  var cameraController = CameraController(
    cameras[0],
    ResolutionPreset.high,
    enableAudio: false,
  );
  await cameraController.initialize().then((value) {}).catchError((e) {
    print('error');
  });
}

onStart() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  startCamera();
  print('setup complete');
}
```

pages:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; // For formatting time
import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart'; 
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

int currentIndex = 1;

Future<void> checkPermission(Permission permission) async {
  final status = await permission.request();
  if (status == true) {
  } else {}
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('Coming soon'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Page2> createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
  String? formattedTime;
  double rating = 0;
  File? _selectedImage; // Define _selectedImage of type File

  Future _pickImageFromCamera() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    print('picker');

    // Get a list of available cameras
    var cameras = await availableCameras();

    // Initialize the camera controller with camera 0
    CameraController cameraController = CameraController(
      cameras[0],
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
      enableAudio: false,
    );

    try {
      // Initialize the camera controller
      await cameraController.initialize();

      // Use the ImagePicker to pick an image from the camera
      final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

      print('pick file');

      // Handle the picked file as needed
      setState(() {
        if (pickedFile != null) {
          _selectedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
        } else {
          print('No image selected.');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error initializing camera: $e');
    } finally {
      // Dispose of the camera controller when done
      cameraController.dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    formattedTime = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              formattedTime!,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50), //distance of title from status bar
            Center(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 134, 203),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: titleController,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Titolo della tua opera (opzionale)',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
                height: 50), // Increased spacing between Titolo and Rating
            Center(
              child: RatingBar.builder(
                initialRating: rating,
                minRating: 0,
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                allowHalfRating: false,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemSize: 48.0,
                itemBuilder: (context, _) => const Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 134, 203),
                ),
                onRatingUpdate: (ratingValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    rating = ratingValue;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0), // Added spacing
            const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Dimensione',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 134, 203),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
                height: 80), // Increased spacing before the photo input area
            Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  print('entering');

                  // Check for available cameras
                  List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();
                  if (cameras.isEmpty) {
                    print('No cameras available.');
                    return;
                  }

                  try {
                    // Use the ImagePicker to pick an image from the camera
                    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker()
                        .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

                    // Handle the picked file as needed
                    if (pickedFile != null) {
                      // Use the picked image file
                      print('Image path: ${pickedFile.path}');
                    } else {
                      print('No image selected.');
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print('Error picking image: $e');
                  }

                  print('exiting');
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 200.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  child: _selectedImage != null
                      ? Image.file(_selectedImage!,
                          fit: BoxFit
                              .cover) // Display the picked image if available
                      : const Icon(
                          Icons.camera_alt,
                          size: 80.0,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page3 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page3({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('Coming soon'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test1">

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>

    <application
        android:label="test1"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

log after a flutter clean:

compilation to app open

```
PS F:\flutterapps\basic page navigation> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K9G in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
W/FlutterJNI( 9612): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
W/FlutterJNI( 9612): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
W/FlutterJNI( 9612): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             52.4s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...          11.7s
I/flutter (15341): setup complete
Syncing files to device M2101K9G...                                194ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on M2101K9G is available at: http://127.0.0.1:63630/JqlkewgOJ6o=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on M2101K9G is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9102?uri=http://127.0.0.1:63630/JqlkewgOJ6o=/
D/ProfileInstaller(15341): Installing profile for com.example.test1
```

permissions given from app:

```
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(15341): Compat change id reported: 78294732; UID 10477; state: ENABLED
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(15341): Compat change id reported: 206033068; UID 10477; state: ENABLED
W/Camera  (15341): The selected imageFormatGroup is not supported by Android. Defaulting to yuv420
E/CameraManagerGlobal(15341): Camera 4 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change
E/CameraManagerGlobal(15341): Camera 5 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change
E/CameraManagerGlobal(15341): Camera 6 is not available. Ignore physical camera status change
I/Camera  (15341): startPreview
I/Camera  (15341): CameraCaptureSession onConfigured
I/Camera  (15341): Updating builder settings
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: ExposureLockFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: ExposurePointFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: ZoomLevelFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: AutoFocusFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: NoiseReductionFeature
I/Camera  (15341): updateNoiseReduction | currentSetting: fast
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: FocusPointFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: ResolutionFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: SensorOrientationFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: FlashFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: ExposureOffsetFeature
D/Camera  (15341): Updating builder with feature: FpsRangeFeature
I/Camera  (15341): refreshPreviewCaptureSession
```

tapping the take a photo widget:

```
I/flutter (15341): entering
I/flutter (15341): Error picking image: PlatformException(no_available_camera, No cameras available for taking pictures., null, null)
I/flutter (15341): exiting
```